# Global keyboard shortcut to eject external hard drive on macOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, external-hard-drive

Is there a global keyboard shortcut to eject an external hard drive? If not, can I install one?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a shortcut in Finder. Select the drive in Finder and press `⌘E`, which is the shortcut for *File » Eject*. This works for any volume (external drives, network shares, disk images).

---

For a global shortcut, use AppleScript. You don't even need a third party tool for a global shortcut. Open *Automator.app*, create a new *Quick Action*, then drag *Run AppleScript* from the left pane.

Enter the following, and replace the name of your volume appropriately:

```
tell application "Finder" to eject disk "foo"
```

Like this:

[image]

Save it, e.g. as "Eject Extreme SSD". It will be stored under `~/Library/Services`.

Go to *System Settings » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts*, and add a global shortcut for your Service.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a global keyboard shortcut so I wouldn't have to click on finder

Comment: Next time, please mention that in the question! Updated the answer.

Comment: The desktop counts as a Finder window, so if it's not too much trouble (and you have your external disks show up on your desktop) just click on the icon and hit [⌘] + [E]

Comment: Necro'ing this post. The option is no longer under Services > General > Eject. In Sonoma 17.3 for whatever reason `⌘ + E` stopped working. Weirdly though, I fixed it by going to that same pane and hitting the `Restore Default` button at the bottom, then done. After that it worked again.

Comment: Updating this, more than 10 years later, and it still works. Note that you have to have System Settings closed when you set up the workflow. It only appears once you (re)start System Settings. @josh

Answer (score 5):

You can create an Automator service that ejects a specified disk.

- Start with a *Get Specified Finder Items* action and drag&drop the volume from the *Computer* view (`Cmd-Shift-C`) in Finder to the list.
- Add an *Eject Disk* action.

Save as any name, and assign a keyboard shortcut in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Services*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have a terminal open already, it can be quick to type

```
$ diskutil list
$ diskutil eject /dev/disk3   # or whatever it is on your machine
```

Typically, your machine has a certain number of onboard volumes, so the first external disk will have a consistent device name. On my machine, it's `/dev/disk3`.

Answer (score 1):

There are no shortcut key to eject external hard drives but you can write an Automator script to eject your hard drives. There is an "eject disk" action. You can then save your workflow as an application, and then use a utility like Spark to set a keyboard shortcut to launch it.

Comment: That sounds like a lot of work if you could just press `⌘E` in Finder.

Comment: I see "eject disk" in the list of actions in automator. However, I can't figure out to get it to eject the external hard drive